# compare products in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.8

In magento we have a functionality for comparing products.But according to the requirements of one of my projects the products should comparable category wise.For example products in mobile category should not be comparable with products in laptop category .But in magento's existing default functionality the products are comparable across any category.

Need suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried any code for this?

Comment: Yup.Tried to fetch products by its category id and then match it with the category id of existing products .But doesnt work properly according to the requirements

Comment: Please share the code. It might miss something

Comment: You should refer this link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648818/compare-only-those-product-who-have-same-category-magento][1]

Thanks


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648818/compare-only-those-product-who-have-same-category-magento